# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

### The situation

I am trying to make what should be a very simple form in my Angular application, but no matter what, it never works.

### The Angular version

Angular 2.0.0 RC5

### The error

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

[image]

### The code

#### The view

```html
<form [formGroup]="newTaskForm" (submit)="createNewTask()">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" required>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### The controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder }  from '@angular/forms';
import {FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { Task } from './task';

@Component({
    selector: 'task-add',
    templateUrl: 'app/task-add.component.html'

})
export class TaskAddComponent {

    newTaskForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder)
    {
        this.newTaskForm = fb.group({
            name: ["", Validators.required]
        });
    }

    createNewTask()
    {
        console.log(this.newTaskForm.value)
    }
}
```

#### The ngModule

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { routing }        from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { TaskService } from './task.service'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [
        TaskService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### The question

Why am I getting that error? Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure that you import the ReactiveFormsModule to the module you use forms with ( for instance auth.module , form.module ) not the app.module .

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I wish I could downvote the Angular team for making the design decisions they made

Comment: I occasionally get this error message in VS Code, although my code is correct. I just have to open the `xxx.module.ts` file and the problems go away immediately. Maybe someone else have the same problem...might be a bug which will be fixed in the future.

Comment: None of the answers below solved my problem. my problem was not adding my component to module declarations. So add your component to `app.module.ts`  `declarations: [YourComponent]`

Comment: If you already have the `ReactiveFormsModule` imported to your component, this error can be a red herring! Be sure you've also added a reference of your module to your app module's `imports`.

Answer (score 2217, accepted):

**RC6/RC7/Final release FIX**

To fix this error, you just need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` from `@angular/forms` in your module. Here's the example of a basic module with `ReactiveFormsModule` import:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

To explain further, `formGroup` is a selector for directive named `FormGroupDirective` that is a part of `ReactiveFormsModule`, hence the need to import it. It is used to bind an existing `FormGroup` to a DOM element. You can read more about it on [Angular's official docs page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroupDirective-directive.html).

**RC5 FIX**

You need to `import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms'` in your controller and add it to `directives` in `@Component`. That will fix the problem.

After you fix that, you will probably get another error because you didn't add `formControlName="name"` to your input in form.

Comment: What I don't get is why one needs to add REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES if FormsModule is being imported inside app.module.  The whole point of modules is to avoid having to declare directives inside components.

Comment: @DanielPliscki You are completely right, I just found out they fixed this problem in RC6 version that was released today. Now you don't need to do this, you only need to import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota  i got this error when i build system in webpack production mode but i build it with a development environment its working fine any idea ?

Comment: I LOST AN HOUR completing forgetting that I created a separate module for my login form in order to lazy load with modules between states.  (I am new to A2, still prefer A1)   Please make sure you use the right module!  Don't be a schmuck like me.  You also no longer need to add to the component.  The imports in your module suffice.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I am confused why this is not mentioned in the guides for FormControls in Angular 2 that I have stumbled upon..

Comment: In Angular 4 I added `ReactiveFormsModule` in the provider list and it worked. Not sure if this is the way you are supposed to do it though.

Comment: I would like to add that I ran into this bug because of casing - I had used [FormControl] instead of [formControl]

Comment: Thanks ! Works fine with Angular 6

Comment: You also have to do this in every involved submodule.https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14288#issuecomment-282531453

Comment: Make sure the change is done in the `imports` section not in the `declarations`

Comment: If Not working again int Ionic android development then put it each module of your page.

Comment: Thanks! In Angular 12 you only need to import ReactiveFormsModule and add it into imports.

Comment: I still occasionally get this error message in VS Code, although my code is correct. I just have to open the `xxx.module.ts` file and the problems go away immediately. Maybe someone else have the same problem...might be a bug which will be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 206):

Angular 4 in combination with *feature modules* (if you are for instance using a shared-module) requires you to also export the `ReactiveFormsModule` to work.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Answer (score 185):

Ok after some digging I found a solution for "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'."

For my case, I've been using multiple modules files, i added ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts

```
 import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ]
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AuthorModule,
],
...
```

But this wasn't working when I use a [formGroup] directive from a component added in another module, e.g. using [formGroup] in author.component.ts which is subscribed in author.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }   from '@angular/common';
import { AuthorComponent } from './author.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AuthorComponent,
  ],
  providers: [...]
})

export class AuthorModule {}
```

I thought if i added ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts, by default ReactiveFormsModule would be inherited by all its children modules like author.module in this case... (wrong!).
I needed to import ReactiveFormsModule in author.module.ts in order to make all directives to work:

```
...
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    FormsModule,    //added here too
    ReactiveFormsModule //added here too
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [...]
})

export class AuthorModule {}
```

So, if you are using submodules, make sure to import ReactiveFormsModule in each submodule file.

Comment: Works for me, exactly the same problem, I really thought modules in exports array will be inherited by children modules... Don't know why exactly !
EDIT : [documentation says](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#exports) exports is to make components, pipes, directives available in the TEMPLATE of any COMPONENT ()

Comment: This is **the solution** if you use **lazy loading** or work with **multiple modules**. Thanks.

Answer (score 70):

I have encountered this error during unit testing of a component (only during testing, within application it worked normally). The solution is to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in `.spec.ts` file:

```
// Import module
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyComponent],
            imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],  // Also add it to 'imports' array
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 36):

1. go to: app.module.ts
2. imports:[
   ....
   ReactiveFormsModule
   ]
3. add this: import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
4. it should look like that:

```js
mport { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  
  ],
  imports: [
    
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 29):

The suggested answer did not work for me with Angular 4. Instead I had to use another way of [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding) with the `attr` prefix:

```
<element [attr.attribute-to-bind]="someValue">
```

Comment: Hey man! Are you sure your answer is related to the question? :) The question was about an issue setting up a form - cause by not properly setting up the ngModule

Comment: @johnnyfittizio Pretty sure. Same scenario, same error message.

Comment: This worked for me, but is strange - why do I need the `attr.` ?

Comment: Thanks a ton. This worked for me also, but I would think there must be something else triggering the problem, like library versioning, or <form> tag positioning?  Strange.

Comment: Found it- the problem was that I needed to import `ReactiveFormsModule` directly into my page's `.module.ts`.  Not the `.page.ts`... once I did that, my template could correctly identify the `formGroup` attribute, without the `attr.` prefix.

Answer (score 29):

The error says that FormGroup is not recognized in this module. So you have to import these (below) modules in **every module** that uses **FormGroup**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Then add FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule into your **Module's** imports array.

```
imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
],
```

You may be thinking that I have already added it in **AppModule** and it should inherit from it? But it is not. Because these modules are exporting required directives that are available only in importing modules. Read more in *[Sharing modules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)*.

Other factors for these errors may be be a spelling error like below...

**[FormGroup]="form"**  Capital **F** instead of small **f**

**[formsGroup]="form"**  Extra **s** after form

Comment: Great answer! I was missing out on a vital import.

Answer (score 21):

Firstly, it is not related to **Angular versions>2**. Just import the following in your *app.module.ts* file will fix the problems.

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Then add FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule into your imports array.

```
imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
],
```

**Note**: You can also import `ReactiveFormsModule` to a specific module instead to `app.module.ts`

Comment: Tried this in Angular 15 and still have the error. :(

Answer (score 20):

If you have to import two modules then add like this below

```
import {ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponentComponent,
    BlogComponentComponent,
    ContactComponentComponent,
    HeaderComponentComponent,
    FooterComponentComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routes,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Jeez Angular, despite using `ng g c myComponent` the component had not been added to the declarations section app.module.ts, after adding it the app compiles. How dumb is this?

Answer (score 17):

Keep in mind that if you have defined "Feature Modules", you'll need to import in the Feature Module, even if you already imported to the `AppModule`. From the Angular documentation:

> Modules don't inherit access to the components, directives, or pipes that are declared in other modules. What AppModule imports is irrelevant to ContactModule and vice versa. Before ContactComponent can bind with [(ngModel)], its ContactModule must import FormsModule.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: thank you so much! I was working for hours on this issue, can't imagine what the problem was... Simply importing my feature Module to app Module fixed the issue.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Missed importing into a module. Thanks!!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue with Angular 7. Just import following in your app.module.ts file.

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Then add FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in to your imports array.

```
imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
],
```

Answer (score 12):

This problem occurs due to missing import of FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule .I also came with same problem. 
My case was diff. as i was working with modules.So i missed above imports in my parent modules though i had imported it into child modules,it wasn't working.

Then i imported it into my parent modules as below, and **it worked!**

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

         @NgModule({
          imports: [
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
      declarations: [MyComponent]
    })
```

Answer (score 12):

> Error ex:error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a
> known property of 'form'.

*I am giving possible reasons and solutions
if the solution works/useful please upvote and make a comment which solution worked for you*

**Scenario 1 and suggestion:** if you have only one module or the error appears in app component

> You have to import the `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule` in the module

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
],
```

**Scenario 2 and suggestion:** when your application contains multiple modules

> Import  FormsModule and reactiveFormsModule in that particular
> module/submodule i.e. nearest module

**Scenario 3 and suggestion:** If you imported FormModule and ReactiveFormModule correctly there might be another problem.

> Maybe you didn't add your component to module declarations in the app
> module. So add your component to module declarations.

```
import { YourComponentName } from './example-file-path/your-component-name.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    YourComponentName
  ]
})
```

**Scenario 4 and suggestion:**
If you added ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule as mentioned in the above.

> Try to reload the project (restart the IDE) and start your server once again with `ng serve`

.

Answer (score 11):

1. Your Angular version is 11+, and you use VisualStudioCode?
2. And you have already imported `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule` and added it into your imports-section within e.g. `app.module.ts` (relevant module can be different, choose the right one):

```
// app.module.ts (excerpt)
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
imports: [
  ...
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  ...
],
```

3. You have the right imports (sometimes there are other libs with similar names); you have defined and initialized your form in your component?

```
// MyWonderfulComponent (excerpt)


import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class MyWonderfulComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup; 
  ...
  constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      // DON'T FORGET THE FORM INITIALISATION
    });
  }
```

4. Your Component-Template has your form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <!-- MY FORM CONTROLS ARE ALREADY HERE --> 
</form>
```

5. And you still get the error message "...since it isn't a known property of..." ?

then just simple restart your VisualStudioCode :)

Comment: Note that you need to import `FormsModule/ReactiveFormsModule` in the module that the component is actually a part of. Blindly putting those in `app.module.ts` is not enough.

Comment: This solution also worked for me in PhpStorm. After a restart it didn't give the warning anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Don't be a dumb dumb like me. I was getting the same error as above, and *none* of the options in previous answers worked. Then I realized I capitalized 'F' in `FormGroup`. Doh!

Instead of:

```
[FormGroup]="form"
```

Do:

```
[formGroup]="form"
```

Answer (score 9):

**Simple solution:**

Step 1: **Import ReactiveFormModule**

```
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Step 2: **Add "ReactiveFormsModule" to the import section**

```
imports: [

    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
```

Step 3: **Restart the application and done**

**Example:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { EscalationManagementRoutingModule } from './escalation-management-routing.module';
import { EscalationManagementRouteWrapperComponent } from './escalation-management-route-wrapper.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [EscalationManagementRouteWrapperComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    EscalationManagementRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class EscalationManagementModule { }
```

Answer (score 9):

add "ReactiveFormsModule" in your <componenet.module.ts> parent

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
        .....
   ],
   imports: [
        .....
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule

    ]
})
export class InvoiceModule { }
```

Answer (score 8):

I was coming across this error when trying to do e2e testing and it was driving me crazy that there were no answers to this.

IF YOU ARE DOING TESTING, **find your *.specs.ts file** and add :

```
import {ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: refer this answer for more clarity how you will add that for unit testing: [@xuhcc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47559288/15063341)

Answer (score 7):

For people strolling these threads about this error. In my case I had a shared module where I only exported the FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule and forgot to import it. This caused a strange error that formgroups were not working in sub components. Hope this helps people scratching their heads.

Answer (score 7):

If you have this problem when you are developing a component, you should add these two modules to your closest module:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
   // other modules
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And if you are developing a test for your components so you should add this module to your test file like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ContactusComponent } from './contactus.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('ContactusComponent', () => {
  let component: ContactusComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContactusComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ContactusComponent],
      imports:[
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ]

    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContactusComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

**A LITTLE NOTE: Be careful about loaders and minimize (Rails env.):**

After seeing this error and trying every solution out there, i realised there was something wrong with my html loader.

I've set my Rails environment up to import HTML paths for my components successfully with this loader (`config/loaders/html.js.`):

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: [ {
    loader: 'html-loader?exportAsEs6Default',
    options: {
      minimize: true
    }
  }]
}
```

After some hours efforts and countless of ReactiveFormsModule imports i saw that my `formGroup` was small letters: `formgroup`.

This led me to the loader and the fact that it downcased my HTML on minimize.

After changing the options, everything worked as it should, and i could go back to crying again.

> I know that this is not an answer to the question, but for future Rails visitors (and other with custom loaders) i think this could be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for this, i finally had to use => minimize: {caseSensitive: true} to get it working

Answer (score 6):

Import and register   ReactiveFormsModule in your app.module.ts.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
HighlightDirective,
TestPipeComponent,
ExpoentialStrengthPipe

],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
ReactiveFormsModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Make sure your spelling is correct in both .ts and .html file.
xxx.ts

```
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
 lastName: new FormControl('')
 });
```

xxx.html file-

```
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm"> 
  <label>
  First Name:
   <input type="text" formControlName = "firstName">
  </label>

  <label>
  Last Name:
   <input type="text" formControlName = "lastName">
   </label>
   </form>
```

I was by mistake wrote [FormGroup] insted of [formGroup]. Check your spelling correctly in .html. It doesn't throw compile time error If anything wrong in .html file.

Answer (score 6):

Using and import **REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is "REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES" literal?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Make sure that if using **submodules** (for example, you not only have app.component.module.ts), but you have a separate component such as login.module.ts, that you include ReactiveFormsModule import in this **login.module.ts** import, for it to work. I don't even have to import ReactiveFormsModule in my app.component.module, because I'm using submodules for everything.

#### File *login.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { LoginPageRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    LoginPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

Comment: that was also a problem in my case. I had enter-credentials-modal-component and login-site-component. it did not work until I did import of FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule  for both of them

Answer (score 6):

I tried almost all the solution here but my problem was a little different(stupid).
I added the component in routing module but didn't include it main module.
So make sure your component is part of the module.

Comment: If your component is a child component, don't forget to add `import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';` to its respective module.

Answer (score 6):

The `ReactiveFormsModule` and `FormsModule` import should be added in your custom component module and also its parent component from where it is getting called.

For example, I needed to add form for my filter component. So I should add this import in my filter module and its parent page (might be list) module from where this filter button gets clicked.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** if you are working inside child module's component, then you just have to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in child module rather than parent app root module.

Comment: This was the magic sauce that was missing for me.

Answer (score 5):

Import **ReactiveFormsModule** in the corresponding module.

Answer (score 5):

If this is just a TypeScript error but everything on your form works, you may just have to restart your IDE.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a formGroup in a modal (entrycomponent), then you have to import ReactiveFormsModule also in the module where the modal is instantiated.

Answer (score 4):

in case you are using standalone components, import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the same component.ts file and in the `@Component` decorator, add a property called `imports` and give it an array containing the `ReactiveFormsModule` as an element. Like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css'],
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
})
export class SigninComponent {
  signinForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl('')
  });
  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
and add it in imports array in the app-module.ts file.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this error message even if you have already imported `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`. I moved a component (that uses the `[formGroup]` directive) from one project to another, but failed to add the component to the `declarations` array in the new module. That resulted in the `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'` error message.

Comment: have you tried to reload the project with an ng serve after the modification?  (if you have embedded modules, you must import the form ans reactive form modules in each and every module using formGroup)

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule` in this module as well as the top level.

If you used a `reactiveForm` in another module then you've to do also this step along with above step: import also `reactiveFormsModule` in that particular module.

For example:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule
],
```

Answer (score 3):

Three main points we have to focus on if encountered such types of issues.

1. Import `ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule` in any shared or app module.
2. If you created a shared module then import that into a module on which you are using the form group and
3. check that component is in
    `declarations: [ ProjectComponent ]` like this.

Answer (score 3):

If you imported FormModule and ReactiveFormModule correctly there might be another problem. Maybe you didn't add your component to module declarations in the app module. So add your component to app.module.ts declarations:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    YourNewComponent
  ]
})
```

Comment: Some times it's also a problem(which is a big problem), I faced same problem

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this error during the last 3 days. I added the ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule as mentionned in the comments above in both of my modules but it had no effect until I reloaded my project with another "ng serve".
I don't know why it didn't reload automatically but at least i'm glad it worked finally!
Any explanation please?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884563/angular-how-to-fix-property-does-not-exist-on-type-error. It happened because sometimes your code is not transpiled and you are seeing old code.

Answer (score 2):

You can import formModule and reactiveFormModule

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ContactComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ContactRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ]
})
export class ContactModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 14 and who uses sub-modules with routing

My issue was related to using sub-modules with routing.
To make it works, follow these three steps:

1- In app.module

```
imports: [
//other-modules
ReactiveFormsModule
```

]

2- In sub-module

```
imports: [
//other-modules
ReactiveFormsModule
```

]

3- In app-routing.module add the following routing (my module was named AuthModule)

```
{
path: 'signup',
component: SignUpComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
]
```

},

Hope this help somebody someday!

Answer (score 1):

`Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'`

means that you try to bind a property using angular (`[prop]`) but angular cant find anything he knows for that element (in this case `form`).

this can happen by not using the right module (missing an import somewhere in the way) and sometimes just cause a typo like:

`[formsGroup]`, with `s` after `form`

Answer (score 1):

import below line in app.modual.ts file and run command `ng s -o` in angular cli.

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not see this particular failure mechanism described here or any reference to `public-api.ts` elsewhere within this issue, so adding it in case it helps someone else.

I have a component built using Reactive Forms inside a feature module.  Following the guidance described in other answers, my module built without issue UNTIL I attempted to export the component via `public-api.ts`.  At that point, I began to get the familiar error `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'`, with no other indication what might be wrong.

This issue occurred for me at this point because I forgot to declare and export the component from the `NgModule`.  Once I added it there, the module began to build again.  So, three things to remember in the `NgModule` when attempting to export a Reactive Forms component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyExportedComponent } from './components/my-exported.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyExportedComponent // this
  ],
    imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule // this
    ], 
    exports: [
        MyExportedComponent // and this
    ],
    providers: [
        ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

At which point, Angular will play nice with this line in `public-api.ts`:

```
export * from './lib/my-module/components/my-exported.component';
```

Answer (score 1):

If, 
 Already Imported

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`
```

in rootModule & customComponentModule & still getting the error

> NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of
> 'form'

just,

> Restart you Application server

this will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, but my component was not being added to the module declarations. To resolve this, add your component to the declarations array in the app.module.ts file: [YourComponent]. Then everything will be okay.

Answer (score 1):

For me I Import ReactiveFormsModule ****But still got the error****, and I found that in my case (I'm using lazy looding), I found the mistak is that instead of importing **login.module** in app-routing. I made a mistake and importing **login-routing.module**

**the Error One**

```
{ 
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/login/login-routing.module').then(m => m.LoginRoutingModule)
  },
```

**FIXED BY THIS**

```
{
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./public/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35159644)

Answer (score 1):

###### You seem to be using FormsModule in your AppModule.ts file. This is compatible with the Template-driven forms In Angular.

###### But in your controller or component file, you are referencing Reactive-form controls In Angular by importing ReactiveFormsModule-based controls. Ex: FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder

###### You can simply fix the error by Importing both modules at your root AppModule.ts file like below:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Note: This is actually a design decision that needs to be taken before developing your application if you are developing an enterprise application based on the complexity of the application forms.

##### Usually, if you compare template-driven forms and reactive-forms in Angular

##### template-driven approach :

- asynchronous nature
- most of the logic is driven by the template

##### reactive-forms driven approach :

- synchronous nature
- most of the logic resides mainly in the component

Answer (score 0):

My solution was subtle and I didn't see it listed already.

I was using reactive forms in an Angular Materials Dialog component that wasn't declared in `app.module.ts`. The main component was declared in `app.module.ts` and would open the dialog component but the dialog component was not explicitly declared in `app.module.ts`.

I didn't have any problems using the dialog component normally except that the form threw this error whenever I opened the dialog:

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was in fact only that I forgot to import and declare the component which holds the form in the module:

```
import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [..., ContactFormComponent, ...],
    imports: [CommonModule, HomeRoutingModule, SharedModule]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule in this module

If you used a reactiveForm in another module then you've to do also this step along with above step: import also reactiveFormsModule in that particular module.

For example:

```
imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and neither the imports nor restarting `ng serve` were the problem. In my case, the problem was that I had copied some Angular 8 code into a new project, which used the `FormBuilder` class to build form groups.

However in newer Angular versions, `FormBuilder` is a typed class. Changing to `UntypedFormBuilder` got the app to compile successfully. Every component in the module was reporting errors with basic bindings, not only `[formGroup]` but also `[routerLink]` and `[ngClass]`, but I only had to fix the `FormBuilder` type in a single component for all of those to go away.

Answer (score 0):

check whether the component uses forms group is added in the declarations of app module.ts

@NgModule({
declarations: ['your component name']})

Answer (score -1):

Say you have structured your app like below:

- `AnotherModule`

  - `<your_form>`
- `AppModule`

Import `ReactiveFormsModule` or `FormsModule` in `AnotherModule` based on your form type.

Make sure `AnotherModule` is imported in `AppModule`.