# Can't bind to FormGroup since it isn't a known property of 'form' (FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule loaded)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-modules

I've just seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form) but I still have the same error. I have a shared module which I import to my feature module. But I also tried import `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule` modules to my feature module directly.

Angular 2.0 Final version.

My shared module is:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-uploader/ng2-uploader';


import { UploadComponent } from './upload/index';

import { AuthenticationService } from './services/index';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ UploadComponent, UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES ],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  providers: [ AuthenticationService ],
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    UploadComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

My feature module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule ],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  exports: [ LoginComponent ]
})

export class LoginModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

The component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../shared';

@Component({
  selector: 'pol-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  notValidCredentials: boolean = false;
  showUsernameHint: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    fb: FormBuilder,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {

      this.loginForm = fb.group({
        username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.emailValidator])],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
      });
...
}
```

And the view:

```
<form class="container" (ngSubmit)="authenticate()" [ERROR ->][FormGroup]="loginForm">
....
</form>
```

All paths and imports are correct. Any ideas? Thanks.

------ [SOLVED] -------

Changed `[FormGroup]="loginForm"` for `[formGroup]="loginForm"` :(

Comment: Change it to `[formGroup]` (camelCase, not PascalCase) and see what happens next?

Comment: Thanks Harry. The Module @angular....forms has no exported member ```formGroup```.

Comment: Sorry Harry. Yes it works. I've changed it on the module, not in view. Sorry and thank you very much :)

Answer (score 18):

Solution:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
```

Import this module to **app.module.ts** or Your Component Class. ( Recommended to import in app.module.ts ).

Then Direct it...ex:---

```
imports: [
   ReactiveFormsModule
]
```

Comment: i already import in app.module.ts, but still getting the same ERROR.

Comment: Please comment with following details:
Which version of angular Project you are working on ?
Are you getting problem while using FormGroup in Material Dialog ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you missed to import ReactiveFormsModule module to your [yourmoduleName].module.ts

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validator, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and add below import your component where you are using formBuilder or formGroup

`imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]`