# reactive/model-driven in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In reference to tutorial here : http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

this is how i am using reactive form in my application :

```
   <div class="login">
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="dologin(form.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" formControlName="username">

        <div [hidden]="form.controls['username'].valid || form.controls['username'].pristine"
        class="alert alert-danger"> Username is required.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [formControl]="form.controls['password']">
        <div [hidden]="form.controls['password'].valid || form.controls['password'].pristine"
        class="alert alert-danger"> Password is required.</div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
</div>


export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    form:FormGroup;
    errorMessage:string;
    public isUserAuthenticated = false;

    constructor(private router: Router,private authenticationService : AuthenticationService,private httpService:HttpService,private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
        this.form=formBuilder.group({
            username:['',Validators.required],
            password:['',Validators.required]
        });

    }
```

but somehow i am getting compilation errors as below:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("     ][formGroup]="form"
>   (ngSubmit)="dologin(form.value)">
>       
>           
>           ][formControl]="form.controls['password']">
>            [ERROR ->]
>       
>           
>           Username
>           [ERROR ->]
>
> "): LoginComponent@4:8 No provider for NgControl ("
>       
>           Password
>           [ERROR ->] ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>   Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors: Can't
>   bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
>    ][formGroup]="form"
>   (ngSubmit)="dologin(form.value)">
>       
>           
>           ][formControl]="form.controls['password']">
>            [ERROR ->]
>       
>           
>           Username
>           [ERROR ->]
>
> "): LoginComponent@4:8 No provider for NgControl ("
>       
>           Password
>           [ERROR ->]http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:17418:19)
>       at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:41756:51)
>       at http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:41678:83
>       at Set.forEach (native)
>       at compile (http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:41678:47)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:96428:28)
>       at Zone.run (http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:96321:43)
>       at http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:96687:57
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:96461:37)
>       at Zone.runTask (http://ws1066.intern.alpha-raid.com:9002/main.bundle.js:96361:47)consoleError @ zone.js:355_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
>   zone.js:357Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse
>   errors:(…)consoleError @ zone.js:357_loop_1 @
>   zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386

I searched about NgControl providers , there i see that i am suppose to import the FORM_Directives but in Angular2.1 they have not mentioned anything about Form directives.

Please help me to figure out , what am i missing here.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "raidar-frontend2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --port 9002 --host ws1069.intern.alpha-raid.com",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.9",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "angular2-localstorage": "^0.4.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.14",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39152110/1565402

Comment: @Ibrahim it worked thanks.