# Angular2 Reactive forms crashes the app

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, formbuilder, reactive

We are working on a Angular2 Projekt, based off mgechev's [Angular2 Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed), trying to use reactive forms to bind the form to data, however Angular2 throws strange errors. The base idea, which we want to use, is the one documented [here on scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-form-validation) as ComplexForm under the headline "Model Driven (Reactive) Forms". Our code regarding the form is the following:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, AppRoutingModule, AboutModule, HomeModule, ExaminerThesisListModule,
    ExaminerOverviewModule, ExaminerCreateThesisModule, StudentOverviewModule, SharedModule.forRoot(), FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

component html

```
<form [formGroup]="formData">
  <div class="well">aa</div>
</form>
```

Note: The app doesn't fail to run, when the `[formGroup]="formData"` attribute is removed. And yes, the html currently contains no input fields, we've commented them out to check if it was them making the app fail, but apparently there seems to be a more basic trivial problem we can't figure out. One of the input fields looks like this and should later be read to the form-tag:

```
 <div class="form-group necessary">
  <label class="input-heading">Intern oder Extern?</label>

  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="externalInternal" value="internal" [formControl]="formData.controls['externalInternal']"> Interne Abschlussarbeit
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="externalInternal" value="external-faculty" [formControl]="formData.controls['externalInternal']"> Abschlussarbeit an externer Fakultät
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="externalInternal" value="external-company" [formControl]="formData.controls['externalInternal']"> Abschlussarbeit an externer Firma
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The actual component typescript code looks like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { ThesesService } from '../shared/theses/theses.service';
import { Thesis } from '../shared/theses/thesis.model';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

/**
 * This class represents the lazy loaded ExaminerOverviewComponent.
 */
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'examiner-create-thesis',
  templateUrl: 'examiner-create-thesis.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['examiner-create-thesis.component.css']
})
export class ExaminerCreateThesisComponent implements OnInit {

  formData: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formData = this.fb.group({
      "thesisType": "bachelor",
      "externalInternal": "internal",
      "titleGerman": "testg",
      "titleEnglish": "teste"
    });
  }

  constructor(private thesesService:ThesesService, private fb: FormBuilder) { };

  submit(formVal: any) {
    console.log("SUBMIT", formVal);
  }
}
```

The error message we get is a

> Unhandled Promise rejection: cannot set property 'stack' of undefined..."

error, from which I can't find any helpful information about our code. I've uploaded a screenshot of the full error stack [here](http://img.lukasbach.com/170125_170849.png).

EDIT: Kostadinov's suggestion of updating zone.js improved the problem by making zone.js returning a more helpful error response, which I've uploaded [here](http://img.lukasbach.com/170126_215645.png).

This problem seems to be the same as documented in [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form), but the solution is already implemented in my code: Their problem was that the [formGroup] directive could not be found as it is implemented by ReactiveFormsModule, but this Module is already imported in AppModule properly, so this should not be causing a problem.

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in a plunker? From what I am seeing, nothing seems to be causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in Zone.js: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3975. Just update to the latest version with:

```
npm install --save zone.js@latest
```

or explicitly:

```
npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4
```

Comment: That at least improved the error message, it still creates an error message though: [screenshot of the error stack](http://img.lukasbach.com/170126_215645.png)

This problem looks like a duplicate from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form), but that doesn't seem to be the problem. The error stack suggests that formGroup is not an available directive for <form>, but the directive is implemented via ReactiveFormsModule, which is imported in my app.module.ts (see above). That still seems very strange for me.

Comment: IS ""@angular/forms" listed under "dependencies" in your package.json? Sometimes removing the whole node_modules directory, and running: "npm install" so everything is re-installed helps with these odd errors.