# Angular 6: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'?

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular6, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have worked with form builder in angular 2/4, But now I am using it in angular 6. I have seen this question ([Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)) but it was for angular 2.
I doing exact same against angular 4 but I am getting this error. Please help:
my code are:

**app.module.ts: ( I have exported FormsModule & ReactiveFormsModule) :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorage } from './services/localStorage.service';
import { HttpModule, RequestOptions, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.route';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }         from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/component';
import { ForgotComponent } from './components/forgotPassword/component';


@NgModule({
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,LoginComponent,ForgotComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,

  ],
  providers: [
    LocalStorage,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

**login.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { LocalStorage } from '../../services/localStorage.service';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { HttpService } from '../../services/http.service';
import { emailRegexp, passwordRegexp } from '../../constants';
@Component({
    selector: 'login-app',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})

/**
 * LoginComponent class
 */

export class LoginComponent {
    private loginForm: any;
    loginValue:any;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private _router: Router,
        private httpService: HttpService,
        private localStorage: LocalStorage,
    ) {
        this.loginValue = new LocalStorage(environment.localStorageKeys.ADMIN).value;

        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(emailRegexp)])],
            password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])]
        });
    }
}
```

**login.component.html: ( Something like this)**

```
 <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="loginForm.valid && login()" novalidate>

 <input type="email" autocomplete="off" (focus)="focusFunction()" placeholder="User Name" formControlName="email" class="form-control">

<div class="col-12">
 <input autocomplete="off" type="password" (focus)="focusFunction()" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
 </div>

 <button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse btn-rounded btn-block">
            <div  *ngIf="!loading" class="sign-in">Sign in</div>
  </button>

  </form>
```

[image: Console Image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add below code in your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and in imports array:

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ]
```

The [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) is a selector for the [`FormGroupDirective`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) Directive which mainly used to Binds an existing [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) to a DOM element and [`FormGroupDirective`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) is available in the [`ReactiveFormsModule`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ReactiveFormsModule) module.

Answer (score 5):

So fiddling around with the same frustrating issue -- a clean angular-cli install and a custom subcomponent/module (component.html... ) and the same error ("Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' "). 
Angular CLI: 7.2.3, Node: 10.9.0, OS: win32 x64, Angular: 7.2.2

I **finally got it to work** based on the above but with a twist
I put the FormsModule & ReactiveFormsModule imports in **app-routing.module.ts** (not app.module.ts) + the subcomponent's ts (in my case: forms-demo.component.ts) :

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
....
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes), 
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
....
```

Afterward ng build/serve worked without any errors.

I'm not an Angular expert but my guess is that the v7 approach whereby app.module.ts delegates to app-routing, that latter file is where the app & component imports & dependencies take place....  YMMV but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I also had to put it in a different place... on my `page.module.ts` (I did leave it in the app.module.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @gloomy.penguin's answer in comment, but a different scenario with the same error.

In my case, I was using a second module and its own routing file.

```
│   app-routing.module.ts
│   app.module.ts
│
└───second-module
    │   second-routing-module.module.ts
    │   second.module.ts
    │
    └───component-1
```

I had to import the following in **second.module.ts** rather than **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
....
@NgModule({
  imports: [
CommonModule,    
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
BrowserModule
]})
```

anyone using a second module, please follow this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import these things in your appmodule.ts

imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Update app.module.ts as follows in belows diff
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule , MatTableModule, MatDialogModule, MatTabsModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatInputModule, MatSelectModule, MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material";
import { MyDialogComponent } from './my-dialog/my-dialog.component';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgxMaterialTimepickerModule} from 'ngx-material-timepicker';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyDialogComponent,
    HighlightDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxMaterialTimepickerModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

Answer (score -2):

Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'? why means ? Answer: ' ReactiveFormsModule ' could not load in your component.you just add component name into rootmodule (app.module.ts)

My solution:

```
**WITHOUT ROUTING**
      **app.modules.ts**
      STEP1 : import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
      STEP2 : check your component (AppComponent)loaded or not
               @NgModule({
                  declarations: [
                     AppComponent
                   ],
               imports: [
                 BrowserModule,
                 AppRoutingModule,
                 ReactiveFormsModule,
                 FormsModule
                ],
             providers: [],
             bootstrap: [AppComponent]
            })
      app.component.html
         use and check <form [formGroup]="registerForm"></form>



 **WITH ROUTING**
    Eg;I have 2 files - form.component.html,form.component.ts

             STEP1:Import and add component(FormComponent) loaded or not in app.component.ts(rootcomponent) below here.
import { FormComponent } from "./form/form.component";
                     @NgModule({
                          declarations: [
                             AppComponent,
                             FormComponent
                           ],
                       imports: [
                         BrowserModule,
                         AppRoutingModule,
                         ReactiveFormsModule,
                         FormsModule
                        ],
                     providers: [],
                     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
                    });
```