# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' with a component inside a page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating an app using Ionic and I've created a page `survey` which is `SurveyPage`. Inside of this page, I've got some texts and a component which is `<app-survey-view>` which is `SurveyViewComponent`

Inside `SurveyViewComponent`, I set a form and I have this error on `[formGroup]="surveyForm"` inside my HTML :

`Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'`

My property `surveyForm` has been well set and it should be working.

I tried to import `ReactiveFormsModule` inside my `app.module.ts` but it isn't working.

Even inside my `SurveyPageModule` I tried to import and export the ReactiveFormsModule but nothing changed.

Can someone help me fixing this ?

Thanks

**EDIT** : After some research, it seems like my page which has a module.ts doesn't let its child inherit the ReactiveFormsModule. I mean, `survey-view`, can't access ReactiveFormsModule which has been declared in its parent's module (SurveyPage)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964204/angular-6-cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale already tried, this didn't work for my case

Comment: Is it possible to provide StackBlitz example with your code?

Comment: plus show the code for app.module.ts and other module

Comment: @PrashantPimpale just uploaded asked code files here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lxsrn1 - 
First time I use this

Comment: @Kamil, Did you import  ```FormsModule``` in imports array at app.module.ts?? As per your stackblitz you have not did that..

Comment: @TestUser I did but removed since it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` into the imports section of the module you are in (or `app.module.ts` if you are not in a specific module). To import these come from

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

If you put it in a sub-module, you should not also reference the `ReactiveFormsModule` in a parent module that imports the module you are in.

I have created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ue2upj) for you on StackBlitz based on your StackBlitz example.

Comment: I just did but it's still not working. Added both modules into survey.module.ts but I'm still having this error

Comment: And you removed the Forms modules (both) from the `app.module.ts`? I noticed you had that in the two places, on your StackBlitz.

Answer (score 0):

surveypage.module.ts.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ForgotpassPage]
})
```

surveypage.html

```
    <form [formGroup]="forgot_form" autocomplete="off">
    <ion-item lines="none" class="input-container">
    <ion-label position="floating" class="input-label">
      Email address
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email" class="input-box"></ion-input>
  </ion-item></form>
```

surveypage.ts

```
    forgot_form: FormGroup;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}
```

Comment: this form is working but my case is that my form is in an external component which has no modules. I just tried your code inside my page, I had not this error anymore. But this code inside the component which is in my page shows the error I wrote in the title