# Can't bind to 'formGroup' in angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I know this may be duplicate question of "[Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)"

I found solution that i have to `import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/forms'`.

But where can i add this reactive form?

Now i'm working in `applyjob.component.html` i think i have to add reative form directives in `applyjob.component.ts` but its not working.

The answer will be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure in the module you've added `ReactiveFormsModule` into the `imports` array

Comment: can you please post your code, HTML and the ts file for the component, and your module ts file.

Comment: Thanks @user184994  i missed in main module, now its working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`formGroup`, `formControl`, etc are all directives that are exposed as a part of the `ReactiveFormsModule`. If you want to use these directives in a Component, you'll have to either import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the Module that this Component is registered in. Or you'll have to export the `ReactiveFormsModule` from some other module(`SharedModule` for instance) and then import that module in the module that you have this Component registered in.

Did you add this?:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
  ...,
  declarations: [..., ApplyJobComponent, ...]
  imports: [..., ReactiveFormsModule, ...],
  ...
})
export class YourModule {...}
...
```