# Angular ngIf formGroup

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have a form on Angular that allows to display an input according to the value selected in a drop-down list.

Here is an example of my code:

(If two is selected an input appears)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqkfyx

If I leave the [formGroup] = "usForm" the input display does not work. On the other hand if I delete [formGroup] = "usForm" of the tag form my code works as I want. So the problem is related to [formGroup] = "usForm"

My html:

```
 <div class="offset-md-2">
  <form [formGroup]="usForm">
    <div class="div-champs">
      <p id="champs">Type
        <span id="required">*</span>
      </p>
      <div class="select-style ">
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="type">
              <option style="display:none">
              <option [value]="o.name" *ngFor="let o of options">
                {{o.name}}
              </option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="champs" *ngIf="selectedOption == 'two'">Appears
      <input type="appears" class="form-control" name="appears">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

My component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-us',
  templateUrl: './create-us.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-us.component.css']
})
export class CreateUsComponent implements OnInit {

  public usForm: FormGroup;
  public selectedOption: string;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.usForm = this.fb.group({
      'type': [null, ],
      'appears': [null, ],
    });
  }

  options = [
    { name: 'first', value: 1 },
    { name: 'two', value: 2 }
  ];
}
```

I simplified my problem as much as in reality it is in a large form with a dozen input

I need your help, thanks in advance

Regards,
Valentin

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant in line *"It does not work if I leave [formGroup] = "usForm" of my form tag. Because the ngIf is not executed"*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Bad if I leave the [formGroup] = "usForm" the input display does not work. On the other hand if I delete [formGroup] = "usForm" of the tag form my code works as I want. So the problem is related to [formGroup] = "usForm"

Comment: Duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)? The rest of the code may be of good use

Comment: @Nuno Thank you for your answer, I also came across this question but it does not answer my problem

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be using `formControlName` instead of `[(ngModel)]`.

And then in comparison, you should be comparing to `usForm.value.type` instead of the `selectedValue`.

Give this a try:

```
<div class="offset-md-2">
  <form [formGroup]="usForm">
    <div class="div-champs">
      <p id="champs">Type
        <span id="required">*</span>
      </p>
      <div class="select-style ">
          <select formControlName="type" name="type">
              <option style="display:none">
              <option [value]="o.name" *ngFor="let o of options">
                {{o.name}}
              </option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="champs" *ngIf="usForm.value.type == 'two'">Appears
      <input type="appears" class="form-control" name="appears">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vv5wc4?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Fixed my ngIf issue, i was leaving out the value portion of the binding. For me it was formGroupName.value.formProperty

Answer (score 1):

Your template is loaded before form group is created. Add ngIf to wail while form group will be created:

```
<div class="offset-md-2" *ngIf="usForm">
    <form [formGroup]="usForm">
```

Comment: that never really happens you know.

Comment: I just tried but it does not work. Thank you for your help, I continue my research