# Angular 6 dynamic form rendering

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I want to build a form reading fields from a list of values:

```
<form [formGroup]="fileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(fileForm.value)">
                            <section class="col col-8">
                                <div>
                                    <label *ngFor="let metadato of metadatiAbilitati" class="input">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="{{metadato.chiave}}"
                                            [formControl]="fileForm.get(metadato.chiave)" />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <label class="input">
                                    <input type="file" name="file" placeholder="seleziona file" />
                                </label> -->
                            </section>
                            <!-- <div> -->
                            <button type="submit">Aggiungi</button>
                            <!-- </div> -->
                        </form>
```

in component ts file I have:

```
constructor(private transazioneService: TransazioneService, fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.fileInputs = [];
    let fields = {};

    this.metadatiAbilitati.forEach(m => {
      let input = this.fileForm.controls[`m.chiave`];
      this.fileInputs.push(input);
      fields[m.chiave] = m.chiave;
    });

     this.fileForm = fb.group(fields);

  }
```

But from browser I got this error:

[image]

Finally, In main module I import ReactiveFormsModule.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: did you add formsModule in your main module?

Comment: possible duplication of this...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form

Comment: No, I Didn't. Is formModule use for template-driven solution? I don't want to use that.

Comment: Yes formModule is must when you use form in your template

Comment: I have also imported FormsModule, but It still doesn't work.

Comment: import ReactiveFormsModule  in your module.or can you paste your module code here

Comment: `
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    homeRouting,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent, ListaTransazioniComponent, CronologiaComponent],
  providers: [TransazioneService]
})
export class HomeModule { }
`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved my problem. Chrome was caching previous changes, so I didn't see right fix.