# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("<form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="loginForm">

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework

I am getting this error while I was messing around with angular. I have tried researching the problem but most of the solutions what I was running into was importing the FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule but mine doesn't work.

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("

<ion-content padding>
  <form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="signupForm">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
"): ng:///SignupPageModule/SignupPage.html@12:8
No provider for ControlContainer
```

I have tried the Imports of the FormsModule,  ReactiveFormsModule in my app.module.ts. and it doesn't work.

Here is my app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],


  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],


  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,



    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input
      formControlName="email"
      type="email"
      placeholder="Your email address"
      [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls['email'].valid &&
      loginForm.controls['email'].touched"
    >
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item
    class="error-message"
    *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['email'].valid &&
       loginForm.controls['email'].touched"
  >
    <ion-label>Please enter a valid email address.</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input
      formControlName="password"
      type="password"
      placeholder="Your password"
      [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls['password'].valid&& loginForm.controls['password'].touched"
    >
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item
    class="error-message"
    *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['password'].valid
      && loginForm.controls['password'].touched"
  >
    <ion-label>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-button (click)="loginUser(loginForm)" expand="block" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
    Log In
  </ion-button>
</form>

<ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" routerLink="/signup">
  Create a new account
</ion-button>

<ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" routerLink="/reset-password">
  I forgot my password 
</ion-button>
```

Comment: And the component have a `FormGroup` called `loginForm`?

Comment: Import `ReactiveFormsModule` in `SignupPageModule`

Comment: may be this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form

Comment: Oh i totall forgot about the module of the signup page . I feel so dumb rn . Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can always read the error message carefully. It usually contains all you need to fix the error

Comment: You will need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in `SignupPageModule`  in order to make all directives to work.