# FormGroup is not working on Ionic with Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have this in my app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SignalRModule.forRoot(createConfig)],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and in my tab1.page.ts I have this:

```
import { FormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
    this.messageFromServerSubscription = this.cs.messageFromServer.subscribe(
      message => {
        this.message = message;
      }
    );
  }

createForm() {
this.form = new FormGroup({
  ipAddress: new FormControl(null, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    validators: [Validators.required]
  })
});
}
```

and in my tab1.page.html I use it like so:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col size-sm="6" offset-sm="3">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label position="floating">Ip Address</ion-label>
                <ion-input 
                  type="text"
                ></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </form>
```

I think I have imported everything right in the app.module and in the tab1.page.ts. How come I still get the error: >> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
Thank you.

Comment: have you declared a property called form inside the `component.ts`

Comment: It is in my " tab1.page.ts"

Comment: so you have a line like `form: FormGroup` in your `tab1.page.ts`

Comment: call the `createForm` in the constructor

Comment: @JohnVelasquez,  NEVER call createForm in constructor. The way is write `<form *ngIf="form"....>`.

Comment: @Ibanez1408, you forget formControlName too!!

Comment: @BearNithi Yes. I have that.

Comment: probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form

Answer (score 0):

declare `form: FormGroup`

you haven't told the file that it needs to exist.

EDIT:1

use formbuilder, `import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';`

inject it into your constructor (which isn't included in your quoted tab1.page.ts file?)

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    ipAddress: ['', validators.required]
});
```

then in the HTML
     ip address

Comment: I have that declared private form: FormGroup;