# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. error in ionic v5.2.2

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework

I have following ionic component which includes a form but every time i access the page web console returns following error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("

<ion-content padding>
 <form [ERROR ->][(formGroup)]="passengregForm">

    <ion-item>
"): ng:///RegisterPageModule/RegisterPage.html@10:7
No provider for ControlContainer ("

<ion-content padding>
 [ERROR ->]<form [(formGroup)]="passengregForm">

    <ion-item>
"): ng:///RegisterPageModule/RegisterPage.html@10:1
No provider for NgControl ("
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Full Name</ion-label>
      [ERROR ->]<ion-input type="text" formControlName="fullname"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button expand"): ng:///RegisterPageModule/RegisterPage.html@14:6
```

and register.module.ts,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

  driverregForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.driverregForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullname: ['', Validators.required],
      nic: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('alert !');
  }

}
```

and register.page.html,

```
<ion-content padding>
 <form [(formGroup)]="passengregForm">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Full Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="fullname"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button expand="full" type="submit" [disabled]="!credentialsForm.valid">Login</ion-button>

  </form> 
</ion-content>
```

cannot find any error on command prompt which runs the app, I've already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form/39152110#39152110) but it wasn't solve the problem.

`app.module.ts` file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { NativeGeocoder } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';

import { SQLitePorter } from '@ionic-native/sqlite-porter/ngx';
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtModule, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { Storage, IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/Camera/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/File/ngx';
import { WebView } from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';

import { RegisterPageModule } from './public/register/register.module';

export function jwtOptionFactory(storage) {
  return {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return storage.get('access_token');
    },
    whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000']
  }
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,RegisterPageModule],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtOptionFactory,
        deps: [Storage],
      }
    })
   ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Geolocation,
    NativeGeocoder,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy
    },
    SQLite,
    SQLitePorter,
    Camera,
    File,
    WebView,
    FilePath
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`ionic version is 5.2.2`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `[formGroup]` instead of `[(formGroup)]`

Comment: actually just try formGroup with no brackets or parenthesis

Comment: Also If you are using `lazy-loading` then you have to import `FormsModule` in `RegisterPageModule` instead of `AppModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare it as follow:

Html

```
<ion-content padding>
 <form [formGroup]="passengregForm">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Full Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="fullname"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button expand="full" type="submit" [disabled]="!passengregForm.valid">Login</ion-button>

  </form> 
</ion-content>
```

Your ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

 @Input() passengregForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.passengregForm= this.formBuilder.group({
      fullname: ['', Validators.required],
      nic: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('alert !');
  }

}
```

Comment: now `No provider for ControlContainer ("` error comes up in web console

Comment: @ Pathum Lakshan -- Can you check if ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule is imported in your app.module.ts and not just the ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: both are imported for sure

Comment: @ Pathum Lakshan --- i edited my answer just see above, i forgot o rename the other variables to the name of your form in the ts and html file, sorry my bad hope it solves the problem.

Comment: `[disabled]="!passengregForm.valid" ` it causes the error :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to use the correct `FormGroup`. You don't have `passengregForm` in your component, but you do have a `driverregForm`. Try doing a

`[formGroup]="driverregForm"` instead (also remove the parentheses)

Comment: Also remember to add the `FormsModule ` and `ReactiveFormsModule` module to `register.module.ts`.

Comment: after that it gives me this  `TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'driverregForm'
TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'driverregForm' ` on web console !

Comment: `Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined` error on `<ion-input type="text" formControlName="fullname"></ion-input>` line

Comment: `formControlName` instead of `(formControlName)`. Using `()` means that you want to use it as an @Output() or event emitter. Without the parentheses, you can use a string as the attribute value, and since `fullname` is a child control, using the name works.

Comment: `TypeError: this.form.get is not a function` error on `<ion-label position="floating">Full Name</ion-label>`

Comment: i also have login component with forms but it works well, once i try to add forms other components it ended up with errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import **ReactiveFormsModule** in app.module.ts

`import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: in ` app.module.ts` ?

Comment: like i said i 've followed one answer and did the same but no effect at all.

Comment: Is `RegisterPage` component declared in app.module or any other module

Comment: In which module it is declared?

Comment: none does it need to declared anywhere, it just used inside routing module only

Comment: Yes. Atleast declare in in app.module

Comment: once it declared in app.module, `Unexpected directive 'RegisterPage' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation`

Comment: You need to declare, not import. Add it in `declarations: []`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Adrita, you need to import the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in **app.module.ts**

And if that doesn't work, it might be because your module is lazy loaded.
In that case import it in the lazy loaded module. In your case it is `register.module.ts`

And one more thing it is **[formGroup]** not **[(formGroup)]**