# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't known property of 'form' - Angular 8 Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I can't use the Reactive Forms inside my Angular 8 / Ionic 4 App. Everytime I got this Error:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template     parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
```

I try a few solutions from stack, but without a solution for me. Here is the Code I use:

### My app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [], 
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, // Forms
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}'
```

### The Page HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="addGame" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item> 

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Title</ion-label>
        <ion-input id="title" type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Url</ion-label>
        <ion-input id="url" type="text" formControlName="url"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Game ID (Intern)</ion-label>
        <ion-input id="gameid" type="text" formControlName="gameid"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Image</ion-label>
        <ion-input id="image" type="text" formControlName="image"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

### The Page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder }  from '@angular/forms';

    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    import { GamesService } from '../../services/games/games.service';


    @Component({
    selector: 'app-add-game',
    templateUrl: './add-game.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-game.page.scss'],
    })
    export class AddGamePage implements OnInit {

    addGame: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private games: GamesService,
        private route: Router,
        formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ){
        this.addGame = formBuilder.group({
            name: [''],
            title: [''],
            url: [''],
            gameid: [''],
            image: ['']
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // ToDo : Add Vendor to form
        console.log('add new game');
    }

    onSubmit(customerData) {
        console.log(customerData);
    }

    }
```

I try this one: [Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)
but still the same error.

What I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need import the ReactiveFormsModule in the module.ts where you declare the AddGamePage too, not only in app.module. https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#sharing-modules

Comment: I try it with follow code:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder }  from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

But the same error

Comment: I want to say. If your component AddGamePage are declared in a module, you need import ReactiveFormsModule in the **module** where you declared the component, not in app.module -in your app.module, your'e not declared (in the tag declare:[...] ) this component- I supouse you're declaring the component in another **module**. Is in this **module** where you need import ReactiveFormsModule (not in component). Really it's not necesary in AppModule

Comment: Tested the code on stackblitz and working fine, see link and answer below. Assume it's just an import issue as mentioned by @eliseo

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong with your code, I created a stackblitz using it and all is working fine
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvpfj1

I'm assuming that means the issue is that you are lazy-loading your page and have not included the form modules in your page module.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other imports ...
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
})
export class PageModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not construct your form in your component constructor (and generally speaking, leave `constructor` alone, except for injection). `ngOnInit` is where you should instanciate your form for your component

Comment: Still the same error when I put the FormBuilder.group into NgInit

Comment: There's no reason to wait for the component initialization to construct the form. It's perfectly fine to do it in the constructor (or, more commonly, as an initializer class property).