# Angular - Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-forms, angular9

I created new app with 2 moodule, when I try to add form to one of my modules I'm getting error:

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
```

I know this is quite common issue so I google a bit and made sure I have ReactiveFormsModule in my module before I wrote this ticket. But I still see an error so issue is obviously there, because of that here is my code:

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    // My providers
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In App modul everything works fine, if I try to make form there things works without any issue.

```
// auth.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  providers: [
    // My providers
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Inside my LoginComponent(which is registered in AuthModule I have code like this:

```
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

and my template is simple as this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form"></form>
```

I verified milion times that I have ReactiveFormsModule imported in both of my modules and also that I have everything saved. I restarted CLI multiple times to make sure it just didn't freez somewhere.

I am out of ideas what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form

Comment: It's not duplicate as I have `ReactiveFormsModule` on it's place.

Comment: Just for checking, Have you tried removing auth.module? and add your component in app.module

Comment: @Niraj Patel  If I add LoginComponent to `app.module.ts` and comment it out from `auth.module.ts` it compile without issues. But it's not solution I'm looking for :(

Comment: Just to be sure, Please check ReactiveFormsModule is imported from "@angular/forms".

Comment: Unfortunately It is imported correctly,

Comment: This is becoming interesting, let me find a solution

Comment: Can you try importing your AuthModule to your AppModule?

Comment: @Lunik I don't think this is solution I would like to go with. It's seems a bit ugly :)

Comment: Can you post the snapshot of the error?

Comment: I'm sorry can you be more exact what you mean by 'snapshot'? Do you want me to make demo on stackbiz or so?

Comment: I mean the image of your error. Your console error's image. And yeah if you put the code up on stackblitz that would could be beneficial as well

Comment: Let me try to create stackblitz

Comment: Sure thing, share that kindly. And have you tried adding FormsModule as well and then ng serving the project again?

Comment: ADDING stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxvfim  - it's throwing some errors now and I try to fix it but this should already give some nice overview how code looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import AuthModule to your AppModule. [Refer Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules#importing-a-feature-module)

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // My providers
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need  to import **BOTH** `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `AuthModule`

```
// auth.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  providers: [
    // My providers
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: Tested, not helped :(

Comment: Just to clarify, Login component is where you use the form?

Comment: Yes @C_Ogoo, form is part of `LoginComponent`

Comment: and authModule is lazy loaded?

Comment: Nope, in `app-routing.module.ts` I just reference auth routes:
`  {
    path: 'admin',
    children: adminRoutes,
  },
`
Routes seems to work without issues as well

Comment: Hmm, then I dont think your `AuthModule` is doing anything, import the FormModule into the AppModule instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211721/discussion-between-andurit-and-c-ogoo).