# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, angular8

Unable to solve Can't bind to formGroup since it isn't a known property of form.

I have already tried all the solutions
already add `ReactiveFormsModule , FormsModule`
also tried `[formGroup]` and `[FormGroup]` still getting the same error

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule , FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ]
```

my form

```
<form [formGroup]="addPostForm" (ngSubmit)="addNewPost()">
     <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="grey" position="stacked">Caption </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="caption"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-button expand="block" type="submit" shape="round">Save</ion-button>
</form>
```

add-post.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router"
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-post',
  templateUrl: './add-post.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-post.page.scss'],
})
export class AddPostPage implements OnInit {

    addPostForm: FormGroup;
    picture = null;
    submitted = false;
    success = false;

    constructor(
        private api: ApiService,
        private FormBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private router: Router,
    ) {
        this.addPostForm = this.FormBuilder.group({
            caption: ['']
        });
    }
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsDn3.png)

Comment: can you please share your component.ts file code?

Comment: Also your component is in another module?

Comment: updated my question and yes it's a different page.

Comment: Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form

Comment: try to refer to this link too, perhaps it will help -> [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-mv8f7l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Also add `ReactiveFormsModule` in AddPostPageModule.ts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup form in **app.component.ts** file. Please refer below code for the same,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  navigate : any;
  //Need to define addPostForm here.
  addPostForm = new FormGroup({
    caption: new FormControl('')
  });
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.sideMenu();
    this.initializeApp();
  }
```

For more reference please refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) angular docs for reactive forms.

**Note:** If your component is imported in another module then in other module you need to import **ReactiveFormsModule** in this module.

Comment: sorry by mistake I shared app.component.ts I have already declared form in add-post.page.ts

Comment: Okay no problem. Now can you please tell me Are you used any module. It means your component is defined in app.module.ts or any other module?

Comment: thanks for the help I hadn't Imported ReactiveFormsModule in my add-post.module.ts which is needed.

Comment: You're welcome I have changed my answer please mark as right if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your component.ts file (the component.ts file for which the form code above has it in the HTML page), please initiate the form

Something like this:

```
addPostForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  caption: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]) // If validators are required, otherwise you can remove the [Validators.required] part.
});
```

Comment: I had made a mistake adding the component.ts file I had already declared my form.