# reactive forms : Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular

So I am trying to create reactive forms but terminal throws me an error just can not understand what is wrong here.
P.S in app.module.ts  I already imported ReactiveFormsModule

here is the code

```
  <form [formGroup]="reciepeForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</div>
                    <div class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Cancel</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id='imagePath' formControlName="name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

here is code from .ts file

```
  reciepeForm: FormGroup;
  this.reciepeForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(),
      'imagePath': new FormControl(),
      'description': new FormControl(),
    })
```

and here is an error [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)

Comment: As @TotallyNewb mentions, you need to import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in your module file.

Comment: It is already imported that is why I can not understand  why it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you either:

- Import the `recipe-edit.module.ts` in your `AppModule`

or

- Declare the `recipe-edit.component.ts` in your `AppModule`

And as @TotallyNewb mentioned, import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `AppModule` as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, reciepeEditComponent  was not in AppModule but I created it using CLI It had to import automatically . Am I right?

Comment: Did declaring it in the AppModule solve your issue? And as to your second point, I am not sure, as it depends on how you generated it with the Angular CLI

Comment: yes it solved .. I just imported the component in app.module . I created it like all other components using ng g c reciepe-edit