# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' for second component

Tags: angular

Something weird is happening in Angular. I started with a component that works fine using a FormGroup, but now I added a second component that also uses FormGroup in the exact same fashion (literally copy-pasted it) and it's giving me the error: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' for second component

For the first component, this is what I did.

In the app.module.ts file I imported

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and added them to:

```
imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RutasModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
```

Then I created a component that imports:

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
```

then declared a component variable `myForm:FormGroup` and used it in the template as

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"> 
   ... 
</form>
```

It works fine, but now I added a second component that literally copies the import and form tag from the first one. Why am I getting this error with the second component? The app.module.ts file does import the required modules and they work fine with the first component, but the second component doesn't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)

Comment: Can you put more of the code from your component where you import formGroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your second component is imported into the App module, if it is imported in another module you need to add `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule` in that component.

Ensure you have created `myForm` variable in secondComponent.ts.

```
myForm = new FormGroup({
     name: new FormControl(),
     age: new FormControl('20')
});
```