# Can't use formGroup in my angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I try to use formGroup in my angular project, but it returns an error :

Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

I have imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule into my auth.module and app.module but I can't seem to solve my error. I hope someone will be kind enough to help me, please.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="username" formControlName="username" type="text" required>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="email" formControlName="email" type="text" required>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="password" formControlName="password" type="password" required>
        <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
    </div>
    <div class="button-form">
        <button class="custom-btn btn-sign-in" type="submit">S'inscire</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**auth.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**app.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MainComponent } from './pages/main/main.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**register.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    });
  }

  submit(): void{
    console.log(this.form.getRawValue());
  }

  btnClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Try restarting the server. May sound silly but have helped me in lots of situations.

Comment: @AakashGoplani I already tried to restart the server but it did not change anything, my error is still present ;(

Comment: Can you please share the whole error description including the path?

Comment: I am sure one of the solution will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/q/39152071/3411606

Comment: Out of curiosity if you cast `form: FormGroup` as just a var `form;` do you still get the same result? A way to reproduce the instance would be nice too with a stackblitz or something.

Comment: @yurzui Error: src/app/pages/auth/register/register.component.html:5:10 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

5    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/pages/auth/register/register.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './register.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegisterComponent.

Comment: @AakashGoplani I have already spent a lot of time on this page but without result...

Comment: @ChrisW. Yeah I get the same result

Comment: Where is this AuthModule loaded from. I don't see any entry in AppModule!

Comment: @AakashGoplani Good point! but now is it normal that I have this error? Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors
export class AuthModule { }                                                                                              The Component 'LoginComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {                                                                  'LoginComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AuthModule'. and 'appModule'

Comment: This is the concept in Angular - you can declare a component only once. So Login Component should only be declared once by any module. Seems like it is declared twice - once by AuthModule and then by AppModule. But the code snippets you have shared I don't see that entry in AppModule, this is strange!

Comment: @AakashGoplani Thank you very much you have solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

This might be an import issue:
If you're using the `RegisterComponent` in another module, be sure to add the `RegisterComponent` to the exports of the `AuthModule` as well

Also noteworthy is that importing the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` into the `AppModule` makes it available throughout your app