# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' but formmodule exist in shared module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm building a login form for a project. I want the form to redirect to the dashboard if the inputted data passes the authentication, But i'm currently experiencing issues with the formgroup. formmodule and reactiveformmodule has been imported in the shared module which is used by both the app module  and the dashboard module. FormGroup works in the dashboard module but shows

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

when used in the  login component located in app module
Below is the snippet to the code.

**Login Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth/auth.service';
import { TokenService } from 'src/app/services/token/token.service';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { Login } from '../login/login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });


  submitted: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private authService: AuthService, 
    private router: Router, 
    private token: TokenService,  
    private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  login(): void {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value)


    const username = this.loginForm.controls['username'].value;
    const password = this.loginForm.controls['password'].value;

    //  //attempting to login 
     this.authService.login(username,password).subscribe(
        res => {
            if(res.status !== 200) {
              this.showToast('error', 'Error', 'User Auth failed');
            }

            if(res.status === 200) {
              this.showToast('success', 'Success', 'User Auth Successful');
              this.router.navigate(['/app'])
            }
            
        }
    );
  }

  showToast(severity: string, summary: string, detail: string) {
    this.messageService.add({severity: severity, summary: summary, detail: detail});
  }


}
```

```html
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" method="post" >
                    
                                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" formControlName="username"  placeholder="Enter username">
                                                    </div>
                            
                                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                                   
                                                        <div class="position-relative auth-pass-inputgroup mb-3">
                                                            <input type="password" class="form-control pe-5" formControlName="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="password-input">
                                                     
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                                        <input class="p-button w-100 d-flex justify-content-center" (onClick)="login()" style="padding: 10px!important" type="submit" value="signin" >
                                                    </div>
                        
                
                                                </form>
```

**SharedModule**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BreadcrumbComponent } from '../shared/components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.component';
import { ButtonComponent } from '../shared/components/button/button.component';
import { DialogComponent } from '../shared/components/dialog/dialog.component';
import { FooterComponent } from '../shared/components/footer/footer.component';
import { MenuitemComponent } from '../shared/components/menuitem/menuitem.component';
import { SidenavComponent } from '../shared/components/sidenav/sidenav.component';
import { TableComponent } from '../shared/components/table/table.component';
import { TopnavComponent } from '../shared/components/topnav/topnav.component';
import { DialogModule} from 'primeng/dialog';
import { TableModule} from 'primeng/table';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { StarterComponent } from './components/starter/starter.component';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {TabViewModule} from 'primeng/tabview';
import {ProgressBarModule} from 'primeng/progressbar';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InteceptorService } from '../inteceptor/inteceptor.service';
import { NgProgressModule } from 'ngx-progressbar';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DynamicFormComponent } from './components/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.component';
import { DynamicFormQuestionComponent } from './components/dynamic-form-question/dynamic-form-question.component';
import { TokenService } from '../services/token/token.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth/auth.service';
import {ToastModule} from 'primeng/toast';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { LoadingbarComponent } from './components/loadingbar/loadingbar.component';
import { ToastsComponent } from './components/toasts/toasts.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BreadcrumbComponent,
    ButtonComponent,
    DialogComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    MenuitemComponent,
    SidenavComponent,
    TableComponent,
    TopnavComponent,
    StarterComponent,
    DynamicFormComponent,
    DynamicFormQuestionComponent,
    LoadingbarComponent,
    ToastsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DialogModule,
    TableModule,
    ButtonModule,
    RouterModule,
    TabViewModule,
    ProgressBarModule,
    NgProgressModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    TokenService,
    MessageService
  ],
  exports: [
    ButtonComponent,
    DialogComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    MenuitemComponent,
    SidenavComponent,
    TableComponent,
    TopnavComponent,
    DialogModule,
    TableModule,
    ButtonModule,
    StarterComponent,
    BreadcrumbComponent,
    CommonModule,
    ProgressBarModule,
    NgProgressModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DynamicFormComponent,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastModule,
    LoadingbarComponent,
    ToastsComponent
  ]
})

export class SharedModule { }
```

**App Module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SharedModule } from '../app/shared/shared.module';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InteceptorService } from '../app/inteceptor/inteceptor.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InteceptorService, multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Dashboard module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ClientindexComponent } from './clientindex/clientindex.component';
import { ShipindexComponent } from './shipindex/shipindex.component';
import { RaftindexComponent } from './raftindex/raftindex.component';
import { CylinderindexComponent } from './cylinderindex/cylinderindex.component';
import { AssessmentindexComponent } from './assessmentindex/assessmentindex.component';
import { AssessmentlogindexComponent } from './assessmentlogindex/assessmentlogindex.component';
import { ItemsindexComponent } from './itemsindex/itemsindex.component';
import { AssessmentcreateComponent } from './assessmentcreate/assessmentcreate.component';
import { AssessmentlogcreateComponent } from './assessmentlogcreate/assessmentlogcreate.component';
import { AssessmentlogeditComponent } from './assessmentlogedit/assessmentlogedit.component';
import { AssessmentlogviewComponent } from './assessmentlogview/assessmentlogview.component';
import { AssessmenteditComponent } from './assessmentedit/assessmentedit.component';
import { AssessmentviewComponent } from './assessmentview/assessmentview.component';
import { ClientviewComponent } from './clientview/clientview.component';
import { ClientraftComponent } from './clientraft/clientraft.component';
import { InvoicesindexComponent } from './invoicesindex/invoicesindex.component';
import { PoindexComponent } from './poindex/poindex.component';
import { WaybillindexComponent } from './waybillindex/waybillindex.component';
import { CertificateindexComponent } from './certificateindex/certificateindex.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  
    DashboardComponent,
        ClientindexComponent,
        ShipindexComponent,
        RaftindexComponent,
        CylinderindexComponent,
        AssessmentindexComponent,
        AssessmentlogindexComponent,
        ItemsindexComponent,
        AssessmentcreateComponent,
        AssessmentlogcreateComponent,
        AssessmentlogeditComponent,
        AssessmentlogviewComponent,
        AssessmenteditComponent,
        AssessmentviewComponent,
        ClientviewComponent,
        ClientraftComponent,
        InvoicesindexComponent,
        PoindexComponent,
        WaybillindexComponent,
        CertificateindexComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)

Comment: no @mutantkeyboard, i've imported all the modules as suggest in the link you shared. the issue here is the formgroup works for views in the dashboard module but doesn't seem to work for a view in the app module although the app module also has the sharedmodule imported in the dashboardmodule

Comment: Could you pls add the code of the app, dashboard and shared modules to the question?

Comment: Remove node_modules and do npm i to see if it fixes something. This happened to me and doing that fixed it

Comment: i have been able to resolve the issue. I needed to place the login component in a module, in other for it to get all the sharedmodule exports