# Upgrading to Angular 11 - NG8002 Error "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'."

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material

So, I am trying to update our project from Angular 8 to Angular 14. I have gone thru the process of updating from 8 to 9 and 9 to 10, before starting the upgrade to 11. When upgrading to 11 though, after running a fresh npm install, I try to ng build and I get multiple gigs worth of errors. It seems like all of the binding has somehow broken now. Most of the errors I get are of the NG8002 variety, such as "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'." or "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'." These errors all go away if I revert back to v10 and reinstall everything.

I have looked into this a lot, and most of the solutions I have found are remembering to import a specific module. However, I have tried importing FormModule, ReactiveFormModule, CommonModule, and the like, but nothing is fixing it. I have also read that it could be missing imports in some sub module, but we are only using the one app.module, unless angular material is somehow counted.

I am at the end of my rope with this, and going nowhere, so any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for the same

Comment: This should answer your question 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152071/cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.